# How do i remove blank array() php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am retrieving post in CI using get_where query, my where variable is chaking for category is this.

I had pass the array of category to get_where query in foreach loop, but if there is no post under category, query gives me blank array in return.

My category array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
           [0] => 341 
           [1] => Email Templates 
           [2] => email-templates 
           [3] => marketing 
           [4] => Email Templates 
           [5] => 340 ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
           [0] => 342 
           [1] => Newsletters 
           [2] => newsletters 
           [3] => marketing 
           [4] => Newsletters 
           [5] => 341 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
           [0] => 343 
           [1] => e-Flyers 
           [2] => e-flyers 
           [3] => marketing 
           [4] => e-Flyers 
           [5] => 341 ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
           [0] => 344 
           [1] => Catalogs 
           [2] => catalogs 
           [3] => marketing 
           [4] => Catalogs 
           [5] => 341 ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
           [0] => 345 
           [1] => Email Stationery 
           [2] => email-stationery 
           [3] => marketing 
           [4] => Email Stationery 
           [5] => 341 ) )
```

above array is my $subcatid;

my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['post'] = $this->post->get_category_post($subcatid);
    print_r($data['post']);
    $this->load->view('frontend/post/category_post', $data);
}
```

in get_category_post; post function

```
function get_category_post($up_cat)
    {
        foreach($up_cat as $cat){
            $query = $this->db->get_where('accmark_posts', array('up_sub_cat' => $cat[0]));
            $result = $query->result();
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
```

this function give me following array

```
Array ( ) 
Array ( )
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( )
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( 
              [up_id] => 1 
              [user_id] => mediaexhibitor 
              [up_time] => 2015-02-15 16:24:11 
              [up_cat] => 340 
              [up_name] => RealEsta - Real Estate Email Marketing      
              [up_name_slug] => realesta-real-estate-email-marketing )
```

I want to remove this blank array() from result.

Comment: Sort your formatting out, its not hard to present the question in a readable way and helps people help ypu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `if` condition in there.

For example:

```
$errors = array_filter($_POST);

if (empty($errors)) {

 echo "array is empty.";
}
else
{
 echo "It is not empty.";
}
```

Or

There are two elements in array and this definitely doesn't mean that array is empty. As a quick workaround you can do following:

```
$errors = array_filter($errors);

if (!empty($errors)) {
}
```

`array_filter()` function's default behavior will remove all values from array which are equal to `null`, `0`, `''` or `false`

Otherwise, in your particular case `empty()` construct will always return `true` if there is at least one element even with "empty" value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter($result)`. If you don't provide a callback function as the second parameter, the function will filter out all array items equal to false, e.g., empty arrays.